# Angular http.post sending empty json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

i have application on AngularJS and NodeJS on the back, when I put my app on VPS, Angular is sending a post with json but object is completely empty, fields are undefined.
Here is my code:

This is my controller:

```
app.controller('fullAppController', ['$scope','$http','$location','$cookies',function($scope,$http,$location,$cookies)
```

My config to provide default options for post:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
}]);
```

My problem:

```
    $scope.registerSubmitData = function(){
      if(propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'userName') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'email') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'password') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'passwordCheck') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'firstName') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'lastName') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'street') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'streetNum') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'postCode') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'city') &&
         propertyCheck($scope.registerData,'state')){
          console.log($scope.registerData); //HERE IS FILLED OBJECT
           $http.post('http://localhost:8000/register', $scope.registerData).success(function(data,status){ 
            // HERE ANGULAR POST A EMPTY JSON
            $location.path('/login');
            $scope.logInSuccesAlert = true;
            $scope.logInSuccesAlertText = "Successfully register";
           }).catch(function(err){
             $scope.registerAlert = true;
             $scope.registerAlertText = "Username exist";
           });
         }else{
           $scope.wrongNoState = true;
           $scope.registerAlert = true;
           $scope.registerAlertText = "Please fill all fields";
           $scope.wrongNoStateText = "Please select state";
         }
    }
```

(I'm using cors)My NodeJS receiving:

```
app.use('/register', function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body);
  //HERE RECEIVED JSON (req.body) IS EMPTY
  var registerData = req.body;
  registerData.password = SHA256(registerData.password);
  insertUser(registerData).then(function(result){
    res.send("Successfully register");
  }).catch(function(err){
    res.status(409).end("User exist");
  });
});
```

How to handle this problem ?

Comment: It seems like the problem in header content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/register', $scope.registerData).success(function(data,status){
```

with:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8000/register', $scope.registerData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).success(function(data,status){
```

You should specify the Content-Type.  If you want all your $http.post to be json you may be able to add that in your default options.